# How to upload a gzipped file without reading everything into memory

Tags: go

I was wondering if anyone can point out how to optimize this further? I don't like the fact that I have to read the entire file into memory and create a byte slice of the file length.

Here's the code:

```
func newfileUploadRequestWithGzip(uri string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, fi.Name())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    filebuffer := make([]byte, fi.Size())
    var gzbuffer bytes.Buffer

    gw, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(&gzbuffer, gzip.DefaultCompression)

    buffer := bufio.NewReader(f)

    if _, err = buffer.Read(filebuffer); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in reading file with error: %v\n", err)
    }

    n, err := gw.Write(filebuffer)
    gw.Close()
    fmt.Printf("%d:%d => %.2f%%\n", n, len(gzbuffer.Bytes()), float32(len(gzbuffer.Bytes()))/float32(n)*100.0)

    io.Copy(part, &gzbuffer)

    if writer.Close() != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    request, requestErr := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    return request, requestErr
}
```

Comment: Your `defer f.Close()` is in the wrong place. It should be immediately after checking for the `os.Open()` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to send a file without reading it into memory; However, it can be done without reading all of its content into memory at once.

If you don't want to read everything into memory *at once*, just don't do it - and get rid of `bytes.Buffer`. Both `gzip.NewWriter` and `multipart.Writer.CreateFormFile` works great with `io.Writer` interface, not just `bytes.Buffer`. `http.NewRequest`, On the other hand, requires an `io.Reader`. While `bytes.Buffer` seems like the best option to implement both, it is not the only option. `io` package provides a `io.Pipe()` to create efficient in memory pipe, which is exactly what we need here.

For example,

```
func newfileUploadRequestWithGzip(uri string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        f.Close()
        return nil, err
    }

    buf := bufio.NewReader(f)
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    multi := multipart.NewWriter(w)
    part, err := multi.CreateFormFile(paramName, fi.Name())
    if err != nil {
        f.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    writer, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(part, gzip.DefaultCompression)
    if err != nil {
        f.Close()
        return nil, err
    }

    go func() {
        _,err := io.Copy(writer, buf)
        w.Close()
        multi.Close()
        writer.Close()
        f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) // panic is not good, but how to make it good depends.
        }
    }()

    request, requestErr := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, r)
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", multi.FormDataContentType())
    return request, requestErr
}
```

This code is very smelly and needs some work to refactor. You function signature, as well as the scope of the function (its' responsibilty) or what you wish the function to do needs change for better error handling and resource management. Suggestions are splitting the function - have one for preparing `io.Writers` and `io.Pipe()`, one for multipart handling, and one for request part; wraping the whole thing into a type and making private helper methods, setting errors concurrently and use a `Err() error` method to collect the erorrs. But without knowing the use case, it is hard to decide and make it praticle - and mostly opinion based.

There is a better-looking code provided by @mh-cbon here : https://play.golang.org/p/i5bocA6-Q4M

Comment: your resource management is messy. File will close before the async routine has copied the data. multi and writer are not closed. Some errors are ignored.

Comment: @mh-cbon Yes, some errors are ignored. Given the scope, i.e., without knowing what happends when you send the request - when the reader is actually is read, it is hard to handle those errors.

Comment: My apologize, I was writing it on mobile. Close code now fixed.

Comment: your last changes are smelly. OP function signature does not fit the problem imho.

Comment: @mh-cbon The code is meant to provide a proof of concept to the use of `io.Writer`s and `io.Pipe()`. It does not serve as a copy-paste solution for the problem (with the problem mostly unknown). The design, like function signature, or the long function body are smelly, so error handling and resource management are smelly too - but it is not the scope or aim here to address that. Without knowing what happens beyond the function, I am at no position to adjust the design.

Comment: @mh-cbon it looks better, but the problem of error handling and responsibility seperation remains aching. I would put your link into the answer.

Comment: i don't agree, as i demonstrated use of a channel error solves all difficulties and lead to correct code, with very little change. it is not about responsibility separation whatnot, it is just about handling most errors.

Comment: Then we need to agree to disagree here. While your code handles all the error, it does not handle it does not handle it in a useful way. The most significant problem is that the error returned by `io.Copy` has significantly different meaning than other errors, and will not trigger without request being sent (and returns its own error on sending request). Handle that error and the error during initializing dependency together, is problematic and non-idomatic to me. Asking a function that creates a request to return a channel, is a sign of bad design to me, either.

Comment: @mh-cbon I think maybe it's worth your own answer. I am leaving this answer as is unless there are errors in code or typos in arguments pointed out. Thanks for the discussion though.

Comment: I don't understand why io.Copy errors are different, all errors are values, all errors are [error](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error). I think channel of error is elegant, and for as long as the writer side is responsible to manage the channel lifetime in a meaningful way, i think the code is sensible to others. that the error is being triggered at initialization or consumption does not matter in the perspective of the function significance, the request will have to be repeated until it succeeds. I don't mean to spam you, but your says ought an alternative opinion for other readers.

Comment: Handling erros does not mean simply print it (log or not). You can retry with other options - but retry only certain steps, like initialazation or `io.Copy`. You can do other things with the error, and that requires logic, and code organization. Say, `io.Copy` returns an `int64` and an `error`, so does `strconv.ParseInt`. Both of the function's result can be sent in a channel, but most of the time, it is not good to put them in the same place.

Comment: @mh-cbon BTW there's a (small) chance that your function makes a write to a closed channel. `L122` could panic if `L83` `defer close(c)` runs first.

Comment: @mh-cbon here's a suggested fix: https://play.golang.org/p/UcegHH6Bngt

Comment: @colminator indeed, somehow. How about a `defer func(){ go func(){...} }()` ?

Comment: @mh-cbon we may be overthinking things. If the request fails, maybe it's sufficient to just return nil & have called check that? Rather than the headache of writing to the error channel in this rare edge-case.

Comment: @colminator i dont think so, especially i dont see headache in using a channel, i see solutions : / https://play.golang.org/p/nIk8O-zItiv

Comment: @mh-cbon interesting! But you still have the deadlock situation. If the request errors - you write to error chan from main go-routine - and no one is listening (as we haven't returned from the function yet). Solution: buffered channel of size 1.